# How make input RESET Button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

#### How make input RESET Button?

**INFO:**
Hi I'm trying to do that if I click on my input which has the ID `search-input` so that if I write something in the input then class `cancel` which is the cross that resets the value it's like `<button type =" reset ">` so if I write something so that it appears to me so`display: block;`and if I delete or input it won't have a value to do`display: none;`and I would like to do all this to make it work even if the user doesn't have Javascript so I would like to do it in PHP version but I don't know what I have so far I only have this code which shows the icon when something is in the input but unfortunately the code has stopped working and especially when I delete the input via the button so the icon doesn't disappear for more information be sure not to be afraid to ask.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("search-input")
const button = document.getElementById("cancel")
const icon = document.getElementById("icon")

input.addEventListener('keyup', test);
button.addEventListener("button", test)

function test() {
  let isShown = false

  if (input.value.trim() == "" || isShown == false) {
    icon.style.display = "none"
    isShown = true
  } else {
    icon.style.display = "flex"
  }
}
```

**PS:** Everything was translated by Google translator if there was a mistake or you did not understand something write and I will definitely tell you how it should be thought in advance thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `addEventListener("button", ...` you mean `click` as in `addEventListener("click", ...`?

Comment: yes i need make if you click on input and write it, show icon, if you delate text or click on `<button type="reset">` disable icon show like `display: none;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Uttam Nath's answer was close to what you wanted but not exactly. This may work better:

**EDIT:** Alright I changed the code a bit and I added the HTML with it so there is no confusion.

```
<body>
  <input type="text" id="search-input">
  <button type="button" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
  <div id="icon" style="background-color: green; width: 50px; height: 50px; display: none;"></div>
</body>
<script>
const input = document.getElementById("search-input");
const button = document.getElementById("cancel")
const icon = document.getElementById("icon");

input.addEventListener('keyup', changeIconDisplay);

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  input.value = '';
  changeIconDisplay();
});

function changeIconDisplay() {
  if (input.value.trim() == "" ) {
    icon.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    icon.style.display = "flex";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: (index):72 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at (index):72:8

Comment: @Whatery1010 that error indicates that the elements are not yet available in the DOM at the time of the query. When are you calling your script?

Comment: @pilchard i am not very good on js i am only learning and know some basic and can you look on my code on website? view-source:https://heexy.org/

Comment: You're welcome @Whatery1010! Website looks good by the way, keep up the good work!

Comment: @ÉmileRoy Oh really thank you <3 Have nice day i am trying be a better developer and with Stackoverflow i can learn more of my bugs Really thank you so much have nice day <3